# AutoHotkey ImageSearch function not working

Tags: macros, autohotkey

how are you?

I'm using AHK v1.1.33.06 and I'm trying to execute a simple script which tries to find an image on whole screen, but it never works, I can see the image on my screen but the code can't haha.

I also tried to look for a part of the complete image, but I get the same error...

This is my code:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#SingleInstance, Force
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
CoordMode Pixel
WinActivate, Kakele
while 1 = 1
{   
    sleep, 5000
    ;ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, 711, 343, Reflect.bmp
    ImageSearch,x,y,0,0,%A_ScreenWidth%,%A_ScreenHeight%, *w12 *h12 Reflect.JPG
    if (ErrorLevel = 2)
        MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
    else if (ErrorLevel = 1)
        MsgBox Icon could not be found on the screen.
    else
        MsgBox The icon was found at %x%x%y%.
    ;sleep, 100
}
return
```

I tried with jpg, png and bmp formats but my code never finds the imgage. I tried *w12 and *h12 because this is the image fragment resolution.

Please see the images I'm trying to look for, the first one is the whole game complete screen, the second one the fragment of the icon on upper left region, the double sword one.

Is there any hint or something I'm doing wrong? I'm going crazy because os this.

### [image: Game Screen]

[image]